# default timeout for providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure what's the default value for the `ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` (in `System.Data.Entity.dll`) property for `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`?

tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing the Command Timeout for SQL command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440130/increasing-the-command-timeout-for-sql-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting `ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` to `null` or not setting it, the default value of the underlying provider will be used.

[MSDN: ObjectContext.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

The default timeout for SQL Server is 30 seconds.

[MSDN: SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)